# OAuth2 Token Refresh Issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, refresh-token, spring-authorization-server

We're using oauth2 for our authentication/authroization, with both refresh and access tokens. Our mobile client makes a refresh token request when the access token expires. However, mobile client encountered an issue handling refresh token .

Here's the scenario:
The user's using app and refresh token request triggers when access token expires.
Mobile client calls to backend to refresh token and concurrently user kills app(the mobile client is not able to get the new token as the app was killed).
The backend processes the refresh token request and issues a new access token.
The user reopens the app after about 20 minutes.
The mobile client automatically makes another refresh token request, but this request uses the old refresh token that was issued before, so the mobile client should logout user.
As a result, this second refresh request fails since it's using an outdated refresh token.

Questions:

How can we handle situations where the app was killed during a pending refresh token request?

We are providing a gracefull period for refresh token, and it is the same as access token expiration, this helps when the user is coming back soon))

Comment: This seems like an edge case that many app developers have probably had to deal with and not an authorization server-specific issue, right? I don't think it would be good to weaken your security posture (for example by disabling refresh token rotation) in order to solve this issue. Would it not be better simply to give the user a nice error message helping them understand what happened? Also, if you extend the session duration of the authorization server or create some type of persistent session, you can fall back to refreshing the access token using `authorization_code` flow.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the mobile client will receive an error with an `invalid_grant` error code, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt#L338). In production this error code should only occur when the refresh token is no longer valid. This needs to be interpreted by the client as a session expired error, and distinguished from other errors.

This ensures a resilient app and the edge case you describe should only occur rarely. The client must then redirect the user to sign in again, which may be a minor usability concern. Alternatively, refresh token rotation could be disabled to prevent this issue. As Steve says in his comment, it is usually recommended to avoid that, since it lowers security.